# Swift 4 iOS Parse JSON to Collection View

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a small problem. I only know how to parse JSON image inks to collection cell if JSON came as "key": "value" But this time I got the type of JSON on the link below...

The trouble is... I have multiples links of images on array ["link", "link", "link"]. How I can put 3-4 images from the first array in one collection view (screenshot below) and then fill other cells

The structure is.. one tableView -> on each cell of TableView I put CollectionView -> Collection has cells with image block with horizontal scroll and title

Screenshot below:

https://d.radikal.ru/d30/1803/60/35717754afbd.png

```
{ "list": [
{
    "title" : "iPhone 5s",
    "images": [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/IPhone_5S.jpg",
        "http://img01.ibnlive.in/ibnlive/uploads/2015/12/apple-iphone5s-151215.jpg",
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5cv-olMz3XKQNhQP4SpwiwqtiDreaBlpESHdCDc6Jm5GjHzRsHcxXrqAI"
    ]
},
{
    "title" : "iPhone 6s",
    "images": [
        "https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1665/26162561181_01148e99ee_b.jpg",
        "https://img1.ibay.com.mv/is1/full/2017/11/item_2028958_545.jpg",
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSz8jIpCOU94HxZEab_vJdl9nGsaAOO18dqq2BXt_L2-PnWhroi",
        "https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3907/15102682838_25e6c90469_b.jpg",
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnMHHcDnMlsrtPpZmfLjQqlJXQNNEvTTg7WWMGcbOHOvxdVUoi"
    ]
},
{
    "title" : "iPhone 7",
    "images": [
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQYu7fKAuYLwQCiilRNCv_wzVZbOpLGsrRzQA7prdgToCiBzsQ",
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGS8lca49LZGvPUtJxrof6DuzvjgKiR_0Nei_b8zeR-3uq1kzyLQ",
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGS8lca49LZGvPUtJxrof6DuzvjgKiR_0Nei_b8zeR-3uq1kzyLQ",
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTko9xdQRKcdJrshSPWCjTtml9eSKiABSN--VhC5YV8MMASVRfgYw",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/10/12/27/iphone-563070_960_720.jpg"
    ]
}
]
}
```

Extension to load photo with a link

```
extension UIImageView{
func downloadImg(from url: String){

let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

    if error != nil{
        print(error)
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    }
}
task.resume()
}
}
```

My object structure

```
struct info : Decodable {
let list : [lists]
}
struct lists : Decodable{
let title : String?
let images : [String]?
}
```

Usually, if JSON has a struct-like "key":"value" I do this.

```
cell.productImage.downloadImg(from: (arrayImg?[indexPath.row].url)!)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please conform to the naming convention that struct names start with a capital letter.

You can decode the URL strings directly to URL and don't declare the properties as optionals if the JSON contains all keys

```
struct Info : Decodable {
    let list : [List]
}
struct List : Decodable {
    let title : String
    let images : [URL]
}
```

Decode the JSON and iterate over the array (`data` is the received `Data` instance)

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Info.self, from: data)
    for phone in result.list {
        for imageURL in phone.images {
          print(imageURL)
        }
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```